# VBA how do i open another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open another workbook, using the code below

```
Sheets("Range").Activate
   Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open ("AvgStdev.xlsm")
```

And it was working before, but now excel is prompting the file cant be found. Help please :/

Comment: `Workbooks.Open ("AvgStdev.xlsm")` - use full path: `Workbooks.Open ("C:\temp\AvgStdev.xlsm")`

Comment: @simoco Post this as an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks ! quick thing i also need to save and close it but this code isnt working:

     Workbooks("C:\Users\Ayaz\Desktop\Analysis\AvgStdev.xlsm").Save
     Workbooks("C:\Users\Ayaz\Desktop\Analysis\AvgStdev.xlsm").Close

Answer (score 11):

You can do what you want easily if you declare your variable as discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).
So if we are to apply it, you can open your workbook like this:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myfilename As String

    myfilename = "C:\Users\Ayaz\Desktop\Analysis\AvgStdev.xlsm"
    '~~> open the workbook and pass it to workbook object variable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename) 

    '~~> More codes here
```

Now later in your code if you are saving the same file:

```
    wb.Save '~~> save
    wb.Close '~~> close
```

Or you can do it using *Close* method only:

```
    wb.Close True '~~> explicit SaveChanges argument to true
```

Now if however you like to save it as another file:

```
    Dim newfilename As String
    newfilename = "C:\Users\Ayaz\Desktop\Analysis\Another.xlsm"
    '~~> If you are saving it in a format other than .xlsx,
    '~~> you have to be explicit in the FileFormat argument
    wb.SaveAs newfilename, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    wb.Close
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your excel file and obtain the filepath from the properties, then substitute the actual filepath into the below:

```
Workbooks.Open ("filepath\AvgStdev.xlsm")
```